# How to re-combine probabilities of predicted classes of equally sized audio chunks to predict class of audio file?

Tags: audio, pytorch, classification, prediction

I want to create a classifier for audio data (insect sounds) with PyTorch. Since the algorithm requires all input to be of the same size, I split each file into equally sized chunks, then train and validate. When making predictions, the algorithm would predict probabilities for each chunk, but I need a prediction for each file. How can I aggregate the 1 to n rows of probabilities of the chunks to a probability for the file?

I have tried to aggregate by calculating the mean, but the result is poor. This is especially true for files where only a few chunks contain a signal and most contain just background noise.

I have also tried to extract signal from noise in advance, but in most cases these cannot be separated clearly.

Is there a state-of-the-art way to make a good prediction for a file from the predictions of its chunks?

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have:

```
chunk1 = torch.tensor([0, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=torch.float)
chunk2 = torch.ones(5) / 5
chunk3 = torch.tensor([0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0])
stacked = torch.stack( (chunk1, chunk2, chunk3) )
stacked
tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
    [0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000],
    [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]])
```

There are many ways to combine these.

If I understand correctly, I think what you're looking for is a way to combine them that under-weights chunk2 (since it contains the least useful information) and overweights chunk1 (which appears to be the most certain).

For the final result, you'll want them to sum to 1.0. This works fine with mean, but if you do anything else you'll either div by sum or take the softmax. Softmax can take arbitrary model outputs for "logits" (log probabilities) so you can just tweak your values and sum them before passing them to softmax.

Where mean gives you a pretty undifferentiated:

```
In [33]: stacked.mean(dim=0)
Out[33]: tensor([0.2333, 0.2333, 0.4000, 0.0667, 0.0667])
```

you could instead do something like:

```
In [45]: stacked.mul(5).sum(dim=0).softmax(dim=0)
Out[45]: tensor([0.0697, 0.0697, 0.8492, 0.0057, 0.0057])
```

Or could also play around with the "temperature" of the softmax, which is effectively just a div factor applied before calling softmax. Below, T=0.5 seems to help:

```
In [50]: stacked.sum(dim=0).softmax(dim=0)
Out[50]: tensor([0.2057, 0.2057, 0.3391, 0.1248, 0.1248])
In [51]: stacked.sum(dim=0).div(2).softmax(dim=0)
Out[51]: tensor([0.2065, 0.2065, 0.2652, 0.1609, 0.1609])
In [52]: stacked.sum(dim=0).div(0.5).softmax(dim=0)
Out[52]: tensor([0.1834, 0.1834, 0.4984, 0.0675, 0.0675])
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. I was more like wondering whether it is possible to use machine learning and train an algorithm to aggregate in order to achieve the best results.

Comment: if the output of your model is the stacked/summed/softmaxed into a single class and you call `backward()` on it, it's going to learn the whole thing. if you want to learn hyperparameters like how much weight it pays to outliers or which architecture to use to combine stacks, you might need hyperparameter search / NAS.